# Coin dollar random class java weird problems

Tags: java

So basically i am assigned to create a Coin class, which consists of a no-argument constructor, void toss method, and getSideUp method that returns the value of the sideUp field.

Then, i have to use this class to create a tossing coins game, where basically we set a variable called balance to 0. I will also need to have 3 objects of the coin class: namely the dime, nickel and quarter. Every time they land heads-up, we should add the value into the balance variable. The game ends when the balance is exceeding or equal to 1 dollar, and you win if you gt 1 dollar.

So far I have the following code:

```
import hsa.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class CoinDollar
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        double balance = 0.0;
        Coin dime = new Coin ();
        Coin nickel = new Coin ();
        Coin quarter = new Coin ();

        while (balance < 1.00)
        {
            dime.toss ();
            nickel.toss ();
            quarter.toss ();

            Stdout.println ("Dime: " + dime.getSideUp ());
            Stdout.println ("Nickel: " + nickel.getSideUp ());
            Stdout.println ("Quarter: " + quarter.getSideUp ());

            if (dime.getSideUp ().compareTo ("Head") == 0)
                balance += 0.10;
            if (nickel.getSideUp ().compareTo ("Head") == 0)
                balance += 0.05;
            if (quarter.getSideUp ().compareTo ("Head") == 0)
                balance += 0.25;

            Stdout.println ("Your current balance is $" + balance);

            Stdout.println ();
        }

        if (balance == 1.00)
            Stdout.println ("You Win!");
        else
            Stdout.println ("You lose! Your balance exceeds $1!");

    }
}


class Coin
{
    private String sideUp;
    private int side;
    private Random abc = new Random ();

    public Coin ()
    {
        side = abc.nextInt (2);
        if (side == 1)
            sideUp = "Head";
        else
            sideUp = "Tail";
    }


    public void toss ()
    {
        side = abc.nextInt (2);
        if (side == 1)
            sideUp = "Head";
        else
            sideUp = "Tail";
    }


    public String getSideUp ()
    {
        return sideUp;
    }
}
```

This program compiles well, but i think theres a problem with the random. Whenever the dime got heads-up, everything are also heads-up (vice versa).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sound like homework ;)

Comment: Try [CodeReview.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: possibly the 3 randoms are created using the same seed (which is usually based on the date), hence contain the same sequence. I would try to use the same random object for the 3 coins.

Comment: BTW: keeping balance as a double value is not a good idea due to rounding issues: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=213

Comment: I ran your code and as @AnubianNoob already mentioned the code looks fine and behaves fine as well. Did you really encounter a problem with the code or do you just think there might be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Random`, simply use `(int)(Math.random() * 2)` at `side = abc.nextInt (2);`, reducing the need for an object, and achieving the same result.

Comment: The default constructor for `Random()` doesn't use the same seed -- it's randomized based on `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: @user3580294 I don't see any other issue. Using a single random also saves memory and processing power.

Comment: Funnily enough, `Math.random()` also uses a `Random`. It's just hidden away.

Comment: @user3580294 thanks for clearing that `System.nanoTime()` caveat, while i actually found it in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29)

Comment: `Math` has a persistent `Random`

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you could be seeing an error in generating random numbers is the way random numbers are generated on computers.

Computers are very deterministic, and thus by nature are not too good at generating random numbers. Fortunately, computer scientists are clever and have figured out ways to generate "pseudorandom" sequences of numbers. A common way that these algorithms generate these sequences starts with a number, called the "seed." The sequence then repeatedly operates on the seed to get new values of the sequence. If the relation is properly designed, this sequence of numbers can be passed off as random.

Usually, the random number generator is seeded by the current time of the system. Thus, if two of these generators are seeded with the same number, they will generate the same numbers. Since your classes are being generated at the same time, the generators will be given the same seed.

More information can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

If you want to work around this, either ensure that the Random object is different by giving a different seed, or instead use the Math library.

```
side = Math.round(Math.random());
```

Math.random() generates a random number between 0 and 1. Math.round() rounds the number to the nearest integer. Since there is a 50-50 chance that the random number is less than 0.5, there is a 50-50 chance that side is either 0 or 1, which is what you are looking for.